# Scala: force method calls in class hierarchy

Tags: scala, inheritance

I have a hierarchy of ConfigBuilder classes which have the role of creating Config instances. My superclass is an *AbstractConfigBuilder* which has a method *build*. I want that build always calls a method *validate* before actually building the object. So, in the abstract super class I have

```
val commonField: String    //one of many fields common to all the hierarchy

abstract def build: Config  //building logic left to the subclasses

def validate: Boolean = {
  // here some common checks
  commonField.size > 0
}
```

In the subclass

```
val subFiled: String

def build: Config = {
   if(validate)                                            // call to validation
      new ConfigImplementation(commonField, subfield) 
   else throw new Error()
}

def validate: Boolean = {
   super.validate            
   subField.size > 0
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to avoid *call to validation* in every subclass of the superclass. My behaviour is clear and fixed: build a config, only after validating its parameters (some common ones in the superclass, the rest in the subclass).
Could you suggest me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just split your `build` into two:

```
protected abstract def buildInternal: Config 
def validate: Boolean

final def build: Config = if(validate) buildInternal else throw new Error()
```

Comment: right. It makes sense. What if I have part of the building logic which is internal? I have a variable 'd' that can be populated already in the super class, only after validation. What is the best way to make this variable available to the subclasses? I could make a 'var' and changed it after validation, but is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Validation should affect values of variables, only check whether the current state is consistent. If you need some sort of intermediate common logic to be executed during the `build`, just make it a function, that returns a value:
`def buildInternal = { val d = computeD; buildUsingD(d) }`

Comment: ^I meant, "validation should _not_ affect values of variables" above, of course.

Comment: ok, so I have to make sure that `buildUsingD(d)` is defined in the main trait/abstract class. This makes the trait not very flexible, since every time I have to  add stuff to the common logic, I have to change the signature of this method (e.g. `buildUsingD(d,e,f)`)

Comment: No, I don't see why think you need it in the base class.