# How to partially abstract a method in Scala

Tags: scala, abstract-class, traits, builder, builder-pattern

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603138/scala-force-method-calls-in-class-hierarchy!).
I have a family of classes of type Config and all of them are built using a builder pattern. Therefore, I have also ConfigBuilder classes that form a hierarchy as well, since many implementation share the same behaviour.

What I want to achieve is that ConfigBuilder expose a method `build` which always perform these steps: validate the parameters (throwing an exception if not valid) and build the Config. Of course I would like to do this with the least possible duplication of code. In fact, the build method can be ideally split in two parts: a common build of the parameters shared by all implementation of Config and a implementation-specific build for each Config.

This is an example of the superclasses

```
abstract class Config {
    def name: String
    def query: String
    def sourceTable: String
}

abstract class ConfigBuilder {
    // common variables are set through setters by the user, which finally calls build

    def build = {
        validate
        val sourceTable = extractFrom(query) // private local method

        // it will contain more fields, extracted from the ones set by the user 
        buildInternal(sourceTable)
    }

    def validate = {
        if(name == null) throw new Exception() // and all common checks 
    }
    abstract def buildInternal(s:String): Config  
}
```

And this is an implementation

```
case class Factlog private ( 
    name:String, query:String, sourceTable:String, description: String)

class FactlogBuilder extends ConfigBuilder {
    // description is set through setters by the user

    def validate = { 
        super.validate()
        if(description == null) throw new Exception()
    }

    def buildInternal(s:String) = 
        Factlog(name,query,s,description)
}
```

This snippet of code works but I would like to understand if this is the best way to do implement the `build` and `buildInternal` method.

1. With this approach, `buildInternal` signature will change with any new Factlog specific parameter, so the solution will be to place the computation of `sourceTable` in ConfigBuilder, outside the method build
2. If I do this, I am forced to generate `sourceTable` before the call to validate
3. As last approach, I could instantiate the variable outside as `var sourceTable = _` and then, after validate method call, give it the value returned by the method `extractQuery`

I am tempted to use the approach 3, but I assume this is not really how Scala should be used. I am sure there are better approaches to compose these hierarchies.

P.S. the list of parameters will surely grow over time, so this is something that I have to consider. Moreover, the builder pattern usage is facilitated by a Spark feature that at the moment I cannot avoid to use.

Comment: just have `bulidInternal`call `extractFrom` directly rather than taking the result as an argument

Comment: so this means that `extractFrom` call should be copied everywhere, in every sub-iimplementation

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve ... If parameters `extractFrom` computes are specific to subclasses, then, of course, you have to call it in each subclass. If they are not, then I don't see what's the problem with your original approach.